# How to create nested ResourceCollections in ember-resource - is this the correct way to do it?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am currently working on an application using ember.js, ember-resource and couchdb.

In my data model I have some nested resources, e. g.

```
MyApp.Task = Ember.Resource.define({
url: '/tasks',
schema: {
    id:          String,
    _rev:        String,
    title:       String,
    description: String,
    comments: {
        type: Ember.ResourceCollection,
        itemType: 'MyApp.Comment',
        nested: true
    }
});

MyApp.Comment = Ember.Resource.define({
    url: null,
    schema: {
        created: Date,
        start: Number,
        end: Number,
        text: String
    }
});
```

Everything works fine as long as I initially provide a "complete" model in the database, i. e. a task with an empty comment model. In this case, I am able to add comments to the task with

```
    var newComment = MyApp.Comment.create({ created: created, start: start, end: end, text: text });
    var comments = task.get('comments');
    comments.pushObject(newComment);
```

However, my initial `task` data doesn't have the embedded `comments`, so I have to create the `Ember.ResourceCollection`for the nested comments programmatically.

I have tried different approaches and tried to find some code in the ember-resource specs, but none of my attempts worked.

My latest approach was

```
var comments = this.get('comments');
if (!comments) {
    comments = Ember.ResourceCollection.create({type: MyApp.Comment, content: []});
    this.set('comments', comments);
}
comments.pushObject(newComment);
```

but this also doesn't work.

So my question is: How can I create a nested model structure in `ember-resource` and save it to the database?

Thanks a lot for any hint!

---

**UPDATE:**

After browsing through the source of `ember-resource` I figured out one way to solve my problem:

```
var comments = this.get('comments');
if (!comments) {
    this.updateWithApiData({comments: []});
    comments = this.get('comments');
}
comments.pushObject(newComment);
```

The method `updateWithApiData` seems to be the one used when reading the data from REST resources.

I still wonder if this is the best / correct way to do it.....

Comment: Found one working solution, so my question is not how to do it at all, but if my solution is a good one.